# Linear Transformations with Basis/Image $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

1. Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $$T(x,y,z)=(x,y+z,2x+y+z,−x+y)$$

(a) Find a basis for $\text{Im}(T)$.

(b) Consider the plane $\pi$ described by the normal equation $−x+y+z=0$. Find a basis for $T(\pi)$.

(c) Consider the plane $\rho$ described as the span $\{(1,1,1),(1,1,−1)\}$. Find a basis for $T(\rho)$.

Here is my thought process. I am looking for some confirmation on my work or corrections/suggestions on how to properly approach the problems

A) I found my kernel which is a point $(0,0,0)$ thus my Image must have three vectors. These vectors I found by inputting the canonic basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $T$ and obtained
$\{(1,0,2,-1),(0,1,1,1), (0,1,1,0)\}$ any of these is a basis of the $\text{Im}(T)$.

B) I am thinking the following. We have a plane $\pi$ which is described with orthogonal information. Am I allowed to say then that the plane $-x+y+z = 0$ can be described as $(x,y,z)\cdot(-1,1,1) = 0$. Therefore I can use $(-1,1,1)$ as an input and plug into $T((-1,1,1))$ which will equal my basis $(-1,2,4,0)$ ?

C) I am thinking $\rho$ is a plane described by the span of two basis. I believe I can turn this into an orthogonal plane by performing the following operations and combining them into one basis.  $(x,y,z)\cdot(1,1,1)$ and $(x,y,z)\cdot(1,1,-1)$. After computing both operations I obtain the basis $(-1,1,0)$ which I can then plug into $T(-1,1,0)$ and obtain the following basis $(-1,1,-1,0)$.

Comment: quibble for A):  I would say $\{(1,0,2,-1),(0,1,1,1),(0,1,1,0)\}$ *is* a basis of the image of $T$ (rather than saying any of these is)

Comment: For B how should I approach it. I assumed that because I was given an orthogonal  plane obtaining only 1 base would suffice.

Comment: for (c), a basis is a set of vectors, not a vector. So there is only one basis, not two (these vectors span (given) and are linearly independent).

Comment: Why do you think that $u\cdot v=0$ implies $Tu\cdot Tv=0$?

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a basis of a vector space is.

Answer (score 1):

(a) You have $$T(x, y, z) = (x,y+z,2x+y+z,−x+y) = x(1,0,2,-1) + y(0,1,1,1) + z(0,1,1,0)$$ So the obvious basis is $\{(1, 0, 2, -1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0)\}$

(b) I think you can solve it this way if I interpreted the question right (if not please correct me in the comments). This is equivalent to $T(y+z,x-z,x-y)$ which is 
$$((y+z),(x-z)+(x-y),2(y+z)+(x-z)+(x-y),-(y+z)+(x-z))$$
$$ = (y+z,2x-y-z,2x+y+z,x-y-2z) $$
$$= x(0, 2, 2, 1) + y(1, -1, 1, -1) + z(1, -1, 1, -2)$$
So, again, the obvious basis is $\{(0, 2, 2, 1), (1, -1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1, -2)\}$

Comment: How did you obtain (y+z, x-z, x-y) ?

Comment: Using the plane equation, $x = y + z$, $y = x - z$, $z = x - y$

Comment: How can the image of a two-dimensional subspace be three-dimensional?